# Application succeeds but SqlAlchemy Zope transaction manager fails to commit intermittently [Pyramid application with Celery tasks]

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pyramid, zope

Brief history:

From past few weeks, we are hitting an intermittent issue with our pyramid web application- Certain DB transactions do not get committed. Although the view responds with success.

We have been trying hard to get a pattern, without success.
On debugging the only difference between a successful and unsuccessful txn is the following:

SUCCESSFUL LOGS:

```
2017-10-22 08:22:41,034 [3360] [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:INFO] ROLLBACK
2017-10-22 08:22:41,034 [3360] [txn.140257118390016:DEBUG] commit 
<zope.sqlalchemy.datamanager.SessionDataManager object at 0x7f9019dbf990>
2017-10-22 08:22:41,034 [3360] [txn.140257118390016:DEBUG] commit
```

UNSUCCESFUL LOGS:

```
2017-10-22 04:45:10,504 [3360] [txn.140257118390016:DEBUG] commit
2017-10-22 04:45:10,504 [3360] [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:INFO] ROLLBACK
```

Notice that SessionDataManager object is missing and the sequence of statements is opposite.

Application setup:

- Sqlalchemy ORM
- Zope transaction manager
- Postgres DB
- Celery
- RabbitMQ
- Pyramid web framework
- Elasticsearch

Relevant code snippets:

DB initialisation
**init**.db

```
import sqlalchemy
import zope.sqlalchemy
import zope.sqlalchemy.datamanager
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
.
.
.
Session = sessionmaker()

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(settings['dburl'])
config.registry['sql_engine'] = engine
config.add_request_method(_session, name='db', reify=True)
```

_session method is as below

```
def _session(request):
 engine = request.registry['sql_engine']
 session = Session(bind=engine)
try:
    tm = request.tm
except AttributeError:
    pass
else:
    zope.sqlalchemy.register(session, transaction_manager=tm)

return session
```

Transaction manager is hooked as follows:

```
config.add_settings({
    "tm.attempts": 3,
    "tm.manager_hook": lambda request: transaction.TransactionManager(),
})
config.include('pyramid_tm')
```

The service code that returns without any exception is:

```
def create_obj(request, data):

# Create an obj from passed data.

created = updated = datetime.utcnow()

obj = models.Obj(**data)
obj.created = created
obj.updated = updated

request.db.add(obj)
try:     
   request.db.flush() # to use the returned id
except Exception as e:
    log.error('Createlog 1: Exception %s occurred while creating annotation %s', e, obj.id)
    raise HTTPConflict()

return obj
```

I have tried to catch the Exception in view as well like this but that hasn't worked to give me more details about it

```
@view_config(context=SqlAlchemyOperationalError)
def failed_sqlalchemy(exception, request):
 log.warning("There was an error in SqlAlchemy!")
 log.warning(request.exception)
 pass
```

Could somebody help me on
1. How I can get more information about the issue?
2. What is the significance of the log pattern that I am seeing?
3. Could my session be getting corrupted due to some race conditions, I am unaware of?

Happy to provide any further details required.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's related to the log you show above, but if a transaction only reads from the database without writing, it will rollback instead of committing it. I guess they did this to reduce the load on the database when checking for serialization errors (if you use SERIALIZABLE isolation level).

Comment: what version of pyramid_tm are you using

Comment: @MichaelMerickel pyramid_tm version is 1.1.1 and pyramid version is 1.7.3

Comment: @AntoineLeclair both the logs are of the same piece of code at different times. This piece of code is writing a new row to the DB. The code is mentioned as service code in my question,

Comment: @AnshulJain Have you made progress on finding the issue here? We have been having intermittent issues while committing data but I don't see any logs or errors around the fails. Once in a while, we see a connection terminated message but not around the time on unsuccessful commits. We started seeing this after upgrade to Postgres 12 and py3 not sure if that are relevant.